# Authentication in foreign data wrapper to Mongodb from PostgreSQL

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, foreign-data-wrapper

I have mongodb and postgreSQL installed in my server. I would like to create foreign data wrapper using [mongo_fdw](https://github.com/citusdata/mongo_fdw). I have enabled authentication for mongodb. How do I specify username/password when creating fdw?

Comment: Your question could be more descriptive but can you pass something via [OPTIONS](https://github.com/citusdata/mongo_fdw#usage) `OPTIONS (address '127.0.0.1', port '27017');` such as username and password? Don't have this environment myself. But it might also help your question if you tried.

Comment: I'll even answer that. From the [current code](https://github.com/citusdata/mongo_fdw/blob/master/mongo_fdw.c#L417-L424) there are no authentication options available for the connection. Raise a JIRA or post your own patch as an answer.

Comment: is there a precompiled version for windows?